# Flexbox height not resizing according to text content inside

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I need to create multiple child containers housing an image and some text where the child container shrinks or expands according to the text in it. The image height needs to be a fixed% (70%) of the child container in which it is placed, allowing the text to wrap it from below. (In Desktop View Mode)

[image]

However, in my case the image is not resizing itself and the inner container remains the same size irrespective of the reduced text in the 2nd-3rd containers.

[image]

The CCS I'm using is as below:

```
.OuterFlexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 1px;
}
.InnerFlexContainer {
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.InnerBlockContainer {
    display:block;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.TextContainer {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 1em;
    margin-inline-end: 1em;
}
.image{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto; /*Changing it to 70% makes the image dissapear*/
    margin: 1em;
}
```

The 'InnerBlockContainer' (Display:Block) is required in addition to the 'InnerFlexContainer' since the 'Image:Float Left' doesn't work inside the Flex Container.

How do I make the 'InnerBlockContainer' and 'InnerFlexContainer' shrink as per the reduced text while also ensuring the image auto-sizes itself to 70% of the container size.

Below is the complete code and JS Fiddle:

```css
.OuterFlexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 1px;
}
.InnerFlexContainer {
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.InnerBlockContainer {
    display:block;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.TextContainer {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 1em;
    margin-inline-end: 1em;
}
.image{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: auto; /*Changing it to 70% makes the image dissapear*/
    margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterFlexContainer">
    <div class="InnerFlexContainer">
        <div class="InnerBlockContainer">
            <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <p>Matheran was identified by Hugh Poyntz Malet, the then district collector of Thane district in May 1850. Lord Elphinstone, the then Governor of Bombay laid the foundations of the development as a future hill station. The British developed Matheran as a resort to beat the summer heat in the region.</p>
                <p>Matheran is the birthplace of freedom fighter Veer Bhai Kotwal. He was born on 1 December 1912 in a Barber family. The state government has built a monument in his memory. The Matheran Hill Railway was built in 1907 by Sir Adamjee Peerbhoy and covers a distance of 20 km (12 mi), over large swathes of forest territory.</p>
                <p>The Matheran hill railway, also known as Matheran Light Railway (MLR), was inspected by UNESCO world heritage site officials but failed to make it to the list as a World Heritage Site. India's other Hill Railways like the Darjeeling Railway, the Kangra Valley Railway, Nilgiri Mountain Railway are already on the list.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="InnerFlexContainer">
        <div class="InnerBlockContainer">
            <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <p>Matheran was identified by Hugh Poyntz Malet, the then district collector of Thane district in May 1850. Lord Elphinstone, the then Governor of Bombay laid the foundations of the development as a future hill station. The British developed Matheran as a resort to beat the summer heat in the region.</p>
                <p>Matheran is the birthplace of freedom fighter Veer Bhai Kotwal. He was born on 1 December 1912 in a Barber family. The state government has built a monument in his memory. The Matheran Hill Railway was built in 1907 by Sir Adamjee Peerbhoy and covers a distance of 20 km (12 mi), over large swathes of forest territory.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="InnerFlexContainer">
        <div class="InnerBlockContainer">
            <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <p>Matheran was identified by Hugh Poyntz Malet, the then district collector of Thane district in May 1850. Lord Elphinstone, the then Governor of Bombay laid the foundations of the development as a future hill station. The British developed Matheran as a resort to beat the summer heat in the region.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mithunu/4d1c2L0b/

Answer (score 0):

Please Add

- **max-width:100px;** in **.image** class

```css
.OuterFlexContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 1px;
}
.InnerFlexContainer {
    display:inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.InnerBlockContainer {
    display:block;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.TextContainer {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 1em;
    margin-inline-end: 1em;
}
.image{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    max-width:100px;
    height: auto; /*Changing it to 70% makes the image dissapear*/
    margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterFlexContainer">
    <div class="InnerFlexContainer">
        <div class="InnerBlockContainer">
            <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <p>Matheran was identified by Hugh Poyntz Malet, the then district collector of Thane district in May 1850. Lord Elphinstone, the then Governor of Bombay laid the foundations of the development as a future hill station. The British developed Matheran as a resort to beat the summer heat in the region.</p>
                <p>Matheran is the birthplace of freedom fighter Veer Bhai Kotwal. He was born on 1 December 1912 in a Barber family. The state government has built a monument in his memory. The Matheran Hill Railway was built in 1907 by Sir Adamjee Peerbhoy and covers a distance of 20 km (12 mi), over large swathes of forest territory.</p>
                <p>The Matheran hill railway, also known as Matheran Light Railway (MLR), was inspected by UNESCO world heritage site officials but failed to make it to the list as a World Heritage Site. India's other Hill Railways like the Darjeeling Railway, the Kangra Valley Railway, Nilgiri Mountain Railway are already on the list.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="InnerFlexContainer">
        <div class="InnerBlockContainer">
            <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <p>Matheran was identified by Hugh Poyntz Malet, the then district collector of Thane district in May 1850. Lord Elphinstone, the then Governor of Bombay laid the foundations of the development as a future hill station. The British developed Matheran as a resort to beat the summer heat in the region.</p>
                <p>Matheran is the birthplace of freedom fighter Veer Bhai Kotwal. He was born on 1 December 1912 in a Barber family. The state government has built a monument in his memory. The Matheran Hill Railway was built in 1907 by Sir Adamjee Peerbhoy and covers a distance of 20 km (12 mi), over large swathes of forest territory.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="InnerFlexContainer">
        <div class="InnerBlockContainer">
            <img class="image" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/30/16/06/water-lily-3784022__340.jpg">
            <div class="TextContainer">
                <p>Matheran was identified by Hugh Poyntz Malet, the then district collector of Thane district in May 1850. Lord Elphinstone, the then Governor of Bombay laid the foundations of the development as a future hill station. The British developed Matheran as a resort to beat the summer heat in the region.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @dhrupal Suthar. Thanks, but this, again, limits all my images to a width of 100px irrespective of the amount of text in each box. I was looking for a way for the images to resize themselves to 70% of container height, with the container height being dependent on the text in the container. Is this possible?! Thanks again for the reply!!

Comment: You can put Height :100%; , but when you put that css image will stretch, but you also try show image center part using **object-fit: cover;** css.